# Is necessary to backup Google Firestore DB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase

Im working a production app in Google's Firebase **Firestore** platform, have been development from a very long time (year and a half ago) and now that its in production I'm worried about backing up and data security at long term.

I know Google's infrastructure its First Class Quality, but I would like to know if somebody using Firestore actually has suffered some kind of data loss from provider or If you guys using Firestore practice periodically updates.

Thanks!